# How to set the distance between line border and edge of window?

Tags: java, swing, border

You know how when you do`panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(txt))`
it creates a border, and if that's the only panel in your window, there will be 
space between the border, and the edge of the window.

But if you do `panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.lightGray, 1))`
the borer is gonna be touching the edge of a window.

**QUESTION**

How do you change the distance between a lineborder and the edge of a window

*comment if not clear enough*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the borer is gonna be touching the edge of a window....How do you change the distance between a lineborder and the edge of a window

You can nest borders  using a [CompoundBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html). For example, to create a 'padding' border around a line border:

```
CompoundBorder cb = new CompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
myComponent.setBorder(cb);
```